# Supervisor + celery : entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly

Tags: celery, supervisord

I am using celery to handle async tasks of my django application and using supervisor to handle celery.

But when i am trying to run it via supervisor, I get below logs on restarting

```
$ sudo tail -f /var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
2019-07-04 13:08:19,298 CRIT received SIGTERM indicating exit request
2019-07-04 13:08:19,436 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2019-07-04 13:08:19,441 INFO /var/tmp/supervisor.sock:Medusa (V1.1.1.1) started at Thu Jul  4 13:08:19 2019
        Hostname: <unix domain socket>
        Port:/var/tmp/supervisor.sock
2019-07-04 13:08:19,465 CRIT Running without any HTTP authentication checking
2019-07-04 13:08:19,466 DEBG supervisord forked; parent exiting
2019-07-04 13:08:19,466 INFO daemonizing the process
2019-07-04 13:08:19,466 INFO supervisord started with pid 21246
2019-07-04 13:08:19,467 INFO spawned: 'celery ' with pid 21248
2019-07-04 13:08:19,782 INFO exited: celery (exit status 1; not expected)
2019-07-04 13:08:19,783 INFO received SIGCLD indicating a child quit
2019-07-04 13:08:20,785 INFO spawned: 'celery ' with pid 21253
2019-07-04 13:08:21,066 INFO exited: celery (exit status 1; not expected)
2019-07-04 13:08:21,066 INFO received SIGCLD indicating a child quit
2019-07-04 13:08:23,070 INFO spawned: 'celery ' with pid 21260
2019-07-04 13:08:23,355 INFO exited: celery (exit status 1; not expected)
2019-07-04 13:08:23,355 INFO received SIGCLD indicating a child quit
2019-07-04 13:08:26,360 INFO spawned: 'celery ' with pid 21265
2019-07-04 13:08:26,638 INFO exited: celery (exit status 1; not expected)
2019-07-04 13:08:26,638 INFO received SIGCLD indicating a child quit
2019-07-04 13:08:27,639 INFO gave up: celery entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

Our config file

```
$ cat /etc/supervisord.conf
[supervisord]
http_port=/var/tmp/supervisor.sock ; (default is to run a UNIX domain socket server)
;http_port=127.0.0.1:9001  ; (alternately, ip_address:port specifies AF_INET)
;sockchmod=0700              ; AF_UNIX socketmode (AF_INET ignore, default 0700)
;sockchown=nobody.nogroup     ; AF_UNIX socket uid.gid owner (AF_INET ignores)
;umask=022                   ; (process file creation umask;default 022)
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB       ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10          ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=debug               ; (logging level;default info; others: debug,warn)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=false              ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                 ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/tmp/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket
;serverurl=http://127.0.0.1:9001 ; use an http:// url to specify an inet socket
;username=chris              ; should be same as http_username if set
;password=123                ; should be same as http_password if set
;prompt=mysupervisor         ; cmd line prompt (default "supervisor")

[program:celery]
command=sudo celery -A myapp worker -l info --autoscale=3,2 --maxtasksperchild=1000
directory=/home/<user>/myapp
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=100
startretries=3
user=root
```

If I run below command directly in terminal, it work fine. Infact thats how it is running right now in `screen` .

```
sudo celery -A myapp worker -l info --autoscale=3,2 --maxtasksperchild=1000
```

But same command in supervisord is giving above mentioned error.

Can someone please help?